# QT how to pass Qlist to class Constructor

Tags: c++, qt

am trying to pass Qlist to class constructor but no success with it. I can pass basic variables but with Qlist am getting error in editor

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Worker'
```

compiler error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Worker::Worker(QList<MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::pnp_com_info>&)'
     Worker* worker = new Worker(pnp_data);
```

here is what am doing.

mainwindow.cpp

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
        ui->setupUi(this);

       // my sample structure
       struct pnp_com_info{
          QString com_name = "";
          int x = 0;
          int y = 0;
          int angle = 0;
          bool status = false;
        };

    QList<pnp_com_info> pnp_data;  // Qlist container
    pnp_com_info pnp_component_data; // struct 

    // fill with data
    pnp_component_data.com_name = "e18";
    pnp_component_data.angle = 600;

    // add it to Qlist container
    pnp_data.append(pnp_component_data);

    //  Worker worker(5); // sample int passed OK.
    // try to pass Qlist to worker constructor 
    Worker* worker = new Worker(pnp_data);  // no success get error : no matching constructor for initialization of 'Worker'
}
```

worker.h source code

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
           struct pnp_com_info{
              QString com_name = "";
              int x = 0;
              int y = 0;
              int angle = 0;
              bool status = false;
            };

   //   Worker(int sampleVar);
     Worker(QList<pnp_com_info> pnpData);
    ~Worker();
public slots:
    void doWork();
signals:
private:
     QList<pnp_com_info> pnp_components_data;
};
#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"

// --- CONSTRUCTOR ---
 Worker::Worker(QList<pnp_com_info> pnp_data) {
//   Worker::Worker(int sampleVar) {
     this->pnp_components_data = pnp_data;

}

// --- DECONSTRUCTOR ---
Worker::~Worker() {
    // free resources
}
// --- PROCESS ---
// Start processing data.
void Worker::doWork() {
   // do some work
}
```

so any idea what am doing wrong. thanks

Comment: what is `Pick_And_Place_Component_info`?

Comment: Please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* output from the compiler into the question. It will probably contain some informational notes that helps understand what's happening. And add a comment in the code showing where the error is.

Comment: Why do you define the same structure twice? I recommend you create a header and place the definition of the structure, then include the header where you want to use it

Comment: @Moia sorry updated question , it as it was from project for stackoverflow had to create simplify it

Comment: @user889030 foo_header.h ```#ifndef PNP_COM_INFO_H
#define PNP_COM_INFO_H

#include <QString>

struct pnp_com_info{
    QString com_name = "";
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int angle = 0;
    bool status = false;
};

#endif // PNP_COM_INFO_H```

Comment: @user889030 then in mainwindow.h: `#include "foo_header.h"` and remove `struct pnp_com_info{ ...`, similar in worker.h

Comment: The lesson here: Don't define a structure in multiple places! Besides having different scope which makes them *different* structures, you also have a major problem if you modify one definition but forget the other (as that leads to *undefined behavior*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worker.cpp, you are not "inside" the class scope. So there you need to fully qualify the type:

```
Worker::Worker(QList<Worker::pnp_com_info> pnp_data) {
```

And then in `MainWindow` you of course need to use the same struct, `Worker::pnp_com_info` and not define a new struct type.

You might want to put the struct definition somewhere else than under `Worker` too. But where, that's impossible to advice on based on just the code you are showing; perhaps having it as nested struct inside `Worker` is a fine place for it.

---

I personally like to use Qt Creator (or whatever IDE I might be using, for any programming language) refactoring functionality to generate the method definition to .cpp file. Write the declaration inside th class in .h file as usual, then right click it to get  context menu, select refactoring and select the generate option you want. Avoids mistakes like this and can save quite a lot if head banging especially when coding while a bit tired.

Comment: @user889030 Same goes for generating new classes: use the Qt Creator new class generation wizards and avoid hassle with forgetting `Q_OBJECT` or something like that. Also for old style signal-slot connections (with `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros), use Qt Creator auto-completion and avoid nasty, sometimes hard-to-notice runtime errors due to typos etc.